# System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'libzkfp.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'

Tags: c#, zkteco

I installed ZKtecoFingerprint SDK and I'm trying to run the demo of this SDK but I got this exception!

```
System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'libzkfp.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'
```

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51zGo.png)

[References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azhaj.png)

How can I use the Zketco demo application??

**Code :**

```
  private void bnInit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmbIdx.Items.Clear();
        int ret = zkfperrdef.ZKFP_ERR_OK;
        if ((ret = zkfp2.Init()) == zkfperrdef.ZKFP_ERR_OK)
        {
            int nCount = zkfp2.GetDeviceCount();
            if (nCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < nCount; i++)
                {
                    cmbIdx.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                }
                cmbIdx.SelectedIndex = 0;
                bnInit.Enabled = false;
                bnFree.Enabled = true;
                bnOpen.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                zkfp2.Terminate();
                MessageBox.Show("No device connected!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Initialize fail, ret=" + ret + " !");
        }
    }
```

[image: Configuration Target x86]

Comment: there are two ways , 1. after the installation better reboot your machine and try again, 2, if these dlls are runtime you may need to import them manually. I haven't used this SDK before. But I would try these options before investigating in detail.

Comment: Have you get any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Finally I found the solution. You have nothing to do. You just need to install the driver comes with sdk. I know this is too much late but  I am writing this answer if later anyone found the solution. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, after doing a lot of headbanging this eventually helped.

Answer (score -1):

Many of these, which connect to devices using SDKs, are 32/64bit related. Change your project configuration to x86 (32bit) and check it again.

Comment: The project configuration target is set to x86 by default , see the update please

Comment: Copy the `libzkfp.dll` manually beside of your `.exe` app in bin debug x86 folder. You can use `DependancyWalker` to check which module is loading or not.
http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/overview_1.htm

Comment: I have already this file in the two folders , but there is no changes